# How can I display more info in an error message when using NUnit Assert in a loop?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, assert

Consider the following code:

```
[Test]
public void WidgetTest()
{
    foreach (Widget widget in widgets)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(0, widget.SomeValue);
    }
}
```

If one of the asserts fails, I will get a very unhelpful error message like the one below:

```
1) Test Failure : WidgetTest.TestSomeValue
  Expected: 0
  But was:  1

at WidgetTest.TestSomeValue()
```

So, the question is, how can I get NUnit to display more useful info, such as the name of the widget, or the iteration of the loop, etc? Even a line number would be more helpful, since this is run in automated manner and I'd like to be able to spot the failing assert without debugging into the code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the overload which takes a message as well:

```
Assert.AreEqual(0, widget.SomeValue,
                "Widget " + widget + " should have SomeValue of 0");
```

Comment: It would be nice if there were a way to decorate he automatically-generated message, rather than having to write your own from scratch.

Comment: @eddiewould this may have changed since your comment but currently it adds the message at the top of the built-in one.