# Can I have an assert inside a loop and get a result for each of the asserts, not just one at the end?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, assert

So I have a table of values that I'd like to process one by one and assert the results. Rather than have multiple asserts I have the Assert inside a loop. This works and it iterates each result in turn, but only provides me with one result. If there are ten items in the table I'd like ten test results - is this possible?

```
[Test]
public void TestOne()
{
    var test = new SemParserLibrary.SemSummaryInfo();
    double[] testValues = new double[] {0, 0.0, 0.1, 1.1, 10, 010, 150, 299, 299.9, 300, 300.0};

    foreach (int i in testValues)
    {
        test.Rate.LogRate = i;
        var testFile = new ParserLibrary.SummaryInfo(test);
        var parsedRecord = ParserLibrary.FileManager.ParseRecord(testFile);
        Assert.AreEqual(parsedRecord.Summary.Data.Rate.LogRate, i, "The de-serialised Rate {0} does not match the input value of {1}", parsedRecord.Summary.Data.Rate.LogRate, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038733/how-can-i-display-more-info-in-an-error-message-when-using-nunit-assert-in-a-loo?rq=1

Comment: Instead of iterating the `testValues` yourself you could create a [Data driven test](https://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/data-driven-tests-with-nunit/).

Comment: That's awesome, looked at the link and refactored my code. Works a treat. :)

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Peter, you can instead use a data-driven test, using `TestCaseAttribute` or `TestCaseSourceAttribute`. That's what I would prefer in your example.

However, just to answer the question as asked, yes it is possible. You would do that like this...

```
[Test]
public void TestOne()
{
    var test = new SemParserLibrary.SemSummaryInfo();
    double[] testValues = new double[] {0, 0.0, 0.1, 1.1, 10, 010, 150, 299, 299.9, 300, 300.0};

    Assert.Multiple(() =>
    {
        foreach (int i in testValues)
        {
            test.Rate.LogRate = i;
            var testFile = new ParserLibrary.SummaryInfo(test);
            var parsedRecord = ParserLibrary.FileManager.ParseRecord(testFile);
            Assert.AreEqual(parsedRecord.Summary.Data.Rate.LogRate, i, "The de-serialised Rate {0} does not match the input value of {1}", parsedRecord.Summary.Data.Rate.LogRate, i);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that my comment seems to answer the question, I will post it as an answer.

[Data driven tests](https://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/data-driven-tests-with-nunit/) allow you to parameterize unit tests with test data. The simplest way to use that would be with the `[TestCase]` attribute:

```
[TestCase(0)]
[TestCase(0.0)]
[TestCase(0.1)]  // etc.
public void TestOne(int i)
{
    var test = new SemParserLibrary.SemSummaryInfo();
    test.Rate.LogRate = i;
    var testFile = new ParserLibrary.SummaryInfo(test);
    var parsedRecord = ParserLibrary.FileManager.ParseRecord(testFile);
    Assert.AreEqual(parsedRecord.Summary.Data.Rate.LogRate, i, "The de-serialised Rate {0} does not match the input value of {1}", parsedRecord.Summary.Data.Rate.LogRate, i);
}
```

This can get tedious if you have a lot of test data. In that case you can use the `[TestCaseSource]` attribute which allows you to get the test data from a static property. In the code for the property you could either hardcode that data or get it from a database or file or any other data source.

Comment: You can also use [DataRow(0.0)] etc if using MSTest: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datarowattribute?view=mstest-net-1.2.0